# How to append all values of each deque in array of deques into one array? (Which also delete the first duplicate node in each deque)

Tags: python-3.x, deque

I have an array contains predicted location by using below loop:

```
for x in range(numStop):
        locationArr.append(random.choice("BCDEFGHIJKLMOPQR"))
```

Then I'm using Dijkstra algorithm apply to each pair element of above array, the return is a array of deque whose each deque contains the path between two node like this:

```
locationArr: ['I', 'C', 'J', 'E']
pathfindingArr: [deque(['I', 'D', 'C']), deque(['C', 'J']), deque(['J', 'C', 'D', 'E'])]
```

I want to add all nodes in each deque in pathfindingArr into single array (also delete the first duplicate node in each deque) like this:

```
completeArr: ['I', 'D', 'C', 'J', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

please help me, I have no idea to do this?! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can be done like this:

```
from collections import deque
pathfindingArr= [deque(['I', 'D', 'C']), deque(['C', 'J']), deque(['J', 'C', 'D', 'E'])]
out = []
for i,deq in enumerate(pathfindingArr):
  for element in deq:
    if len(out)==0:
      out.append(element)
    else:
      if not element == out[len(out)-1]:
        out.append(element)

print(out)
```

Test the code above [here](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes)